# database disk image is malformed with dnf on Fedora 29

Tags: fedora, dnf

*I have cross-posted this on [ask.fedora.org](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/132374/database-disk-image-is-malformed-with-dnf-on-fedora-29/) as I am still uncertain whether this or the other side has the larger Fedora userbase.*

For a few days now I could not install updates due to this error:

```
# env LC_ALL=C dnf update
Last metadata expiration check: 0:18:57 ago on Wed Jan 23 16:16:14 2019.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dnf", line 58, in <module>
    main.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 179, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 64, in main
    return _main(base, args, cli_class, option_parser_class)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 99, in _main
    return cli_run(cli, base)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 123, in cli_run
    ret = resolving(cli, base)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 146, in resolving
    base.resolve(cli.demands.allow_erasing)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 760, in resolve
    self._transaction = self._goal2transaction(goal)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 681, in _goal2transaction
    ts.add_upgrade(pkg, upgraded, obs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/db/group.py", line 269, in add_upgrade
    ti_new = self.new(new, libdnf.transaction.TransactionItemAction_UPGRADE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/db/group.py", line 222, in new
    reason = self.get_reason(pkg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/db/group.py", line 237, in get_reason
    return self.history.swdb.resolveRPMTransactionItemReason(pkg.name, pkg.arch, -1)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/libdnf/transaction.py", line 788, in resolveRPMTransactionItemReason
    return _transaction.Swdb_resolveRPMTransactionItemReason(self, name, arch, maxTransactionId)
RuntimeError: Step: database disk image is malformed in

        SELECT
            ti.action as action,
            ti.reason as reason
        FROM
            trans_item ti
        JOIN
            trans t ON ti.trans_id = t.id
        JOIN
            rpm i USING (item_id)
        WHERE
            t.state = 1
            /* see comment in TransactionItem.hpp - TransactionItemAction */
            AND ti.action not in (3, 5, 7, 10)
            AND i.name = 'python2-rpkg'
            AND i.arch = 'noarch'
        ORDER BY
            ti.trans_id DESC
        LIMIT 1
```

I found that one shall do these commands in order to fix it, and I tried, but it has not resolved the problem.

- `dnf clean all`
- `dnf makecache`
- `rpm --buildddb`

On [Ask Fedora somebody suggested](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/90379/fedora-24-dnf-sqlite3databaseerror-database-disk-image-is-malformed/) that dnf is not able to recover from that and that one has to repair the SQLite database manually.

I have tried to run the command given,

```
sqlite3 history-<date>.sqlite ".dump" | sqlite3 history-<new date>.db && rm history-<date>.sqlite
```

Doing it on `/var/lib/dnf/history/history-2015-10-25.sqlite` had no effect. Doing it on `/var/lib/dnf/history.sqlite` resulted in a new error:

```
# dnf update
Letzte Prüfung auf abgelaufene Metadaten: vor 1:22:29 am Mi 23 Jan 2019 16:39:44 CET.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 64, in main
    return _main(base, args, cli_class, option_parser_class)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 99, in _main
    return cli_run(cli, base)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 123, in cli_run
    ret = resolving(cli, base)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 146, in resolving
    base.resolve(cli.demands.allow_erasing)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 760, in resolve
    self._transaction = self._goal2transaction(goal)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 657, in _goal2transaction
    ts.add_install(pkg, obs, reason)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/db/group.py", line 256, in add_install
    ti_new = self.new(new, libdnf.transaction.TransactionItemAction_INSTALL, reason)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/db/group.py", line 219, in new
    rpm_item = self._pkg_to_swdb_rpm_item(pkg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/db/group.py", line 210, in _pkg_to_swdb_rpm_item
    rpm_item = self.history.swdb.createRPMItem()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/db/history.py", line 291, in swdb
    self._swdb = libdnf.transaction.Swdb(self.dbpath)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/libdnf/transaction.py", line 729, in __init__
    this = _transaction.new_Swdb(*args)
RuntimeError: Exec failed: malformed database schema (1467577792)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dnf", line 58, in <module>
    main.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 179, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 64, in main
    return _main(base, args, cli_class, option_parser_class)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 121, in __exit__
    self.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 472, in close
    self._finalize_base()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 455, in _finalize_base
    self.history.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/db/history.py", line 305, in close
    self.swdb.closeTransaction()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/db/history.py", line 291, in swdb
    self._swdb = libdnf.transaction.Swdb(self.dbpath)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/libdnf/transaction.py", line 729, in __init__
    this = _transaction.new_Swdb(*args)
RuntimeError: Exec failed: malformed database schema (1467577792)
```

Looking further into the `sqlite3 .dump` thing, I see this:

```
/var/lib/dnf# sqlite3 history.sqlite .dump 
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
/**** ERROR: (10) disk I/O error *****/
ROLLBACK; -- due to errors
```

However, when I copy this `history.sqlite` into `/tmp` and execute that `.dump` there, I get a sensibly looking database. Also opening it with the GUI `sqliteman` works fine. It seems that the database itself is okay.

Dumping the database into a new file somewhere else and copying it back then gives me this:

```
/v/l/dnf# dnf update
Letzte Prüfung auf abgelaufene Metadaten: vor 0:30:51 am Sa 26 Jan 2019 13:21:13 CET.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 64, in main
    return _main(base, args, cli_class, option_parser_class)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 99, in _main
    return cli_run(cli, base)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 123, in cli_run
    ret = resolving(cli, base)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 146, in resolving
    base.resolve(cli.demands.allow_erasing)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 760, in resolve
    self._transaction = self._goal2transaction(goal)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 650, in _goal2transaction
    reason_obsolete = ts.get_reason(obsolete)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/db/group.py", line 237, in get_reason
    return self.history.swdb.resolveRPMTransactionItemReason(pkg.name, pkg.arch, -1)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/libdnf/transaction.py", line 788, in resolveRPMTransactionItemReason
    return _transaction.Swdb_resolveRPMTransactionItemReason(self, name, arch, maxTransactionId)
RuntimeError: Step: disk I/O error in

        SELECT
            ti.action as action,
            ti.reason as reason
        FROM
            trans_item ti
        JOIN
            trans t ON ti.trans_id = t.id
        JOIN
            rpm i USING (item_id)
        WHERE
            t.state = 1
            /* see comment in TransactionItem.hpp - TransactionItemAction */
            AND ti.action not in (3, 5, 7, 10)
            AND i.name = 'libmodulemd'
            AND i.arch = 'x86_64'
        ORDER BY
            ti.trans_id DESC
        LIMIT 1


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dnf", line 58, in <module>
    main.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 179, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 64, in main
    return _main(base, args, cli_class, option_parser_class)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 121, in __exit__
    self.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 473, in close
    self.reset(sack=True, repos=True, goal=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 504, in reset
    self.history.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/db/history.py", line 305, in close
    self.swdb.closeTransaction()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/db/history.py", line 291, in swdb
    self._swdb = libdnf.transaction.Swdb(self.dbpath)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/libdnf/transaction.py", line 729, in __init__
    this = _transaction.new_Swdb(*args)
RuntimeError: Exec failed: disk I/O error
Exception ignored in: <function SwdbInterface.__del__ at 0x7f28b02e4510>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/db/history.py", line 262, in __del__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/db/history.py", line 305, in close
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/db/history.py", line 291, in swdb
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/libdnf/transaction.py", line 729, in __init__
RuntimeError: Exec failed: disk I/O error
```

I also restored the SELinux labels, but that did not change anything, it is

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root unconfined_u:object_r:rpm_var_lib_t:s0 29M 26. Jan 13:52 history.sqlite
```

Root can also read the file:

```
/v/l/dnf# head -c 1000 history.sqlite 
SQLite format 3@  ,�,.,P��⏎
```

How is this on Fedora 29, can I recover from this?

Comment: Have you tried `dnf clean dbcache`?

Comment: The question from ask fedora you refer to has a solution as th first answer.  Did you run those commands?

Comment: I did, but it did not help. The question is updated accordingly.

Comment: @maulinglawns: I did, but it turned out to be already included in `dnf clean all`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Not a Fedora user myself. I have used `yum clean dbcache` with success on CentOS.

Comment: Please file a bug report in https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Fedora -- thanks!

Comment: @mattdm: Okay, I did so, [here is the report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1669824).

Comment: Fwiw, I hit this too, though in my case the package was appstream-qt. None of the rpm/dnf cache/cleanup commands helped, and it had nothing to do with SELinux either. In the end I did an `rpm -e --nodeps` to temporarily remove the package, and the upgrade put in place the new version automatically. Bit unnerving since I've not hit troubles during the upgrade for many years now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this dump again after restarting the system. Perhaps the restoration of SELinux labels needed to be adjusted. Now the updates seem to work again.

Answer (score 0):

I am developing a Docker image of some Centos-like OS and encountered this error. U can play with it using my image:

```
docker run --rm -it pasaopasen/redos7.3:2023-12-07_22-19 bash
```

Try to perform:

```bash
dnf update -y
dnf install nginx -y
```

and u will see same error.

Nothing helped me to solve this problem, it seems like the result of bad global updates of the `rpm`, `python3` and so on. I've solved it just through global update from some old VM instance backup